# How to insert character in a string at a specific position?

Tags: php, arrays, string, position, addition

```
$str="Hello From Other Side ";
$add = rand(20,50);
```

How can I insert a number or character as `(25)` after every character in a string at a specific position?

**result**

```
He25llo Fr25om Ot26her S25ide
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the  `substr()` function!

If u want to insert `25` inside `$str="Hello From Other Side ";` at the position 2!

U can do

```
$pos=2;
$new_string= substr($str, 0, $pos). "25" . substr($str, $pos);
```

and the results would be:

```
"He25llo From Other Side "
```

Comment: thank u brother - how to add to all  
"He25llo Fr25om Ot25her Si25de "